# How to pass a variable for the default value in dbUtils Text widgets in python notebooks

Tags: python, databricks, azure-databricks

This is python notebook code in databricks , I dont want to hardCode the 2nd parameter , instead I want to set it in a variable and pass that variable to text method

```
 defaultValue = "2092"
 dbutils.widgets.text('yearvalue', defaultValue)
```

when i run this notebook , it displays a empty textField alone . So How to pass a variable as parameter to text and get it populated as default value

Comment: In my Azure Databricks enviornment the valie 2092 is succesfully set as default value for the parameter. Have you tried your code on a fresh notebook and perhaps on a newer runtime version?

Comment: The code is working fine, it is displaying text field with `2092` as default when `defaultValue` variable is passed. The Databricks runtime version that I am using is 10.4 LTS. Please try running it on newer runtime version as suggested by @restlessmodem

Comment: works just fine for me as well

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned in the comment, the code you are using will work fine irrespective of the Databricks runtime that you are using. But once you edit the text to replace the value, and execute the same code again, it does not reflect in the text box. You can see the following demonstration.

**First Execution**

[image]

**Editing the value to blank and executing again**

[image]

So, once these text widgets are edited, they don’t regain the default value when the piece of code is executed again. Instead, they have the value that you have manually given to them (by editing the text field widget). Refer to this [official Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/dev-tools/databricks-utils#:%7E:text=text%20command%20(dbutils.widgets.text)) to understand more about `dbutils.widgets.text()`